# Correct Directory for Procfile for Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to migrate a basic Python blog / website to Heroku to deploy it to the internet.  I'm partially through the process and am having trouble getting the Procfile correct.  I am following the instructions shown [here for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python).

"Mysite" is the top level directory of my site.   I've placed the virtualenv within it, per the instuctions.

I'm not sure where the Procfile needs to go - here's the error I'm running into:

```
C:\Users\andre\mysite>virtualenv venv
Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\andre\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32'
New python executable in venv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

C:\Users\andre\mysite>venv\Scripts\activate
(venv) C:\Users\andre\mysite>pip freeze > requirements.txt
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(venv) C:\Users\andre\mysite>pip install -r requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wheel==0.24.0 in c:\users\andre\mysite\venv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(venv) C:\Users\andre\mysite>heroku local web
ERROR: open Procfile: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've attempted placing the Procfile several different places, but haven't had any luck eliminating the error.

The Procfile I'm using has the following contents:

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi --log-file -
```

The file directory is as follows:

```
andre/
    -Documents/
    -Desktop/
    -AppData/
        -Local/
             -heroku/
    -mysite/
        -blog/
        -mysite/
        -venv/
        -db.sqlite3
        -manage.py
        -Procfile
        -requirements.txt
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong here?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Move it up one directory to the root of your repository, and remove the `.txt` extension. From [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-naming-and-location):

> A Procfile is a file named `Procfile`. It should be named `Procfile` exactly, and not anything else. For example, `Procfile.txt` is not valid. The file should be a simple text file.
>
> The file must be placed in the root directory of your application. It will not function if placed in a subdirectory.

This documentation applies to all languages supported by Heroku. When the documentation says "the root of your application" it refers to the root directory, not a Django app.

Comment: Thanks Chris.   I tried moving the Procfile up in the directory, but that didn't help - the same error resulted.   I've revised to show a little more depth of my directory that might shed some more light.  Basically, the "andre" folder is a general directory for my computer.  Also, I've struck the ".txt" from Procfile, but that isn't helping either.

Comment: @AME, it looks like your `Procfile` references a file that doesn't exist: `mysite.wsgi`. Do you have  WSGI file?

Comment: That is correct, Chris, I had assumed configuring / locating WSGI files would come later in the process although I could be mistaken.   Do you think that's the issue?  I assumed that the issue was that the Procfile wasn't being located and read in the first place.  I do have a WSGI.py file further down in the directory (@ andre/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py).  Should things be moved there?  Thanks again.

Comment: @AME, I don't think the WSGI file needs to be in the root, and the `Procfile` certainly shouldn't be moved. Try editing the `Procfile` and replacing `mysite.wsgi` with `path/to/your/real/WSGI.py`.

Comment: Got it - unfortunately still having the same problem.  One more idea - is it possible that my requirements.txt file is incorrect?  Its only contents is "wheel==0.24.0" - does that appear wrong?  I also tried switching the Procfile text to "web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT" per  the suggestion listed in the text here but that had no effect either: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python

Comment: @AME, so `gunicorn` isn't installed? What happens if you try running the exact command from the `Procfile` manually, e.g. `gunicorn path/to/your/real/WSGI.py --log-file -`?

Comment: I get an error from not having gunicorn.  After installing "gunicorn" with pip and rerunning, I'm still get an error from running the command manually because module "fcntl" isn't available from gunicorn.  I believe some inadequacy of gunicorn in Windows is why the documentation advises replacing the Procfile contents with ""web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT" but then again with that I go back to square one where heroku can't find Procfile.  Could Windows be responsible for Procfile being not found?  Thanks again for all the help with this.

Comment: @AME, [`fcntl` is specific to Unix hosts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html). It is not available on Windows, and I'm not sure why your code needs it. At this point I think we have solved your original question. Stack Overflow [works best with one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts). Please consider posting a new question about `fcntl`.